# how to get the mean of a column between two patterns iteratively using awk.

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large file with this format

```
#1995GO
CCD3    0.099   -0.008      0.047       0.019       2       2       4
CCD7    0.090   -0.040      0.000       0.000       1       1       4
#

#1995SM55
CCD3    0.174    0.026      0.026       0.047       4       4       10
CCD7    0.157    0.006      0.015       0.011       5       5       10
#

#1999TC36
CCD3    0.080    0.019      0.008       0.001       2       2       4
CCD7    0.085    0.032      0.004       0.014       2       2       4
#
```

I want to get the mean of the column 4 of each content between # #. For example for the first I want to print ((0.047 + 0.000 )/ 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short **`awk`** approach:

```
awk '/^#[0-9]/{ f=1;next }/^#[[:space:]]*$/{ print s/c; f=c=s=0 }f{ ++c; s+=$4 }' file
```

The output:

```
0.0235
0.0205
0.006
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using awk:-

```
awk '
        !/^#/ {
                T += $4
                C += 1
        }
        /^#$/ {
                printf ( "%.3f\n", ( T /C ) )
                T = C = 0
        }
' file
```